# Add parameter to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, file-upload, addeventlistener

I have the following code to upload a file with `JavaScript` (because I want to show a progress bar):

```
function uploadFile() {
    var e = _("file").files[0],
        n = new FormData;
    n.append("file", e);
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest;
    a.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, !1), a.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, !1), a.open("POST", "upload.php"), a.send(n)
}
```

But how can I add an additional POST parameter, e.g. for the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I found the solution myself.

It's possible to simply add a GET parameter, like this:

```
function uploadFile() {
    var e = _("file").files[0],
        n = new FormData;
    n.append("file", e);
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest;
    a.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, !1), a.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, !1), a.open("POST", "upload.php?my_parameter=my_value"), a.send(n)
}
```

Then, in my PHP code, I can access the parameter like this:

```
echo $_GET['my_parameter'];
```